# Switching circuit or relay

Tags: switches, ac, relay, dc

I'm new here and don't know much more about electronics.I need a switch/relay that help me off DC line when AC (grid) line is available and automatically turn on when AC (grid) line is not available.

Some Details here:

We use 12 v car battery for home dc lights and dc fans, because there is energy crises in my country. I want some sort of switch/relay that help me switch off my dc line whenner my AC grid (220v AC) available.

AC= 220 v
DC= 12 v (200AH battery)

6 Lights = 12 v , 5W
3 fans= 12v , don't know watt.

If
AC=0 then DC= 1,  AC= 1 then Dc = 0

Thanks

Comment: You need to measure/estimate the maximum current supplied from the battery so that the relay contact ratings can be chosen correctly.

Comment: As well as switching over from the DC to AC supply it might be useful to start charging the battery when the mains AC is available.

Comment: Hello Nasir and welcome to EE.SX. While your question is valid, EE.SX exists as a Q&A service for electronics engineers and students of EE. The site requires specific questions about methods you have already tried. Since you have not attempted a solution, this question will be closed. If you can edit the question to include a schematic and/or photo of an existing attempt, then it may be salvageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be as simple as powering a relay from the AC line.  Many relays will be available with coils intended for you AC line voltage and frequency.

The relay is then a switch that is thrown one way when there is AC power, and the other way when there isn't.  Generally these relays will be at least SPDT (single pole double throw).  That means there is a common contact that is switched to be connected to one of two other contact.  The three leads are often referred to as COM (common), NO (normally open), and NC (normally closed).

Put the COM and NC leads of the relay in series with the 12 V battery.  That switch will be on when there is no power applied to the relay coil, and off when there is.

Make sure that the relay contacts are rated for the maximum current everything you connect to the battery could draw.